# printf from Nucleo to Windows-7 virtual COM doesn't work in X-NUCLEO-IKS01A1 example

Tags: c++, stm32, mbed

I want to run Nucleo example HelloWorld_IKS01A1 and do the printf's out the Nucleo's USB port to my Windows-7 virtual COM port to my HyperTerminal, but nothing comes out.

If I do the printf example, it display at HyperTerminal ok.

I added these lines:
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
DigitalOut myled(LED1);

I used :
[Firmware Library for X-NUCLEO-IKS01A1 (MEMS Inertial & Environmental Sensors) Expansion Board](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/ST/code/X_NUCLEO_IKS01A1/file/f507d4465c31/Components/lsm6ds3/lsm6ds3_class.h)

..and then changed each printf to pc.printf, but nothing prints out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this:

Accel driver top page:
https://developer.mbed.org/teams/ST/code/X_NUCLEO_IKS01A1/file/f507d4465c31/Components/lsm6ds3/lsm6ds3_class.h
   HelloWord
   Import to Compiler > Import 
Replace its main() with
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

DigitalOut myled(LED1);

int main() {
  int i = 1;
  pc.baud(9600);
  pc.printf("Hello World !\n");
  while(1) { 
      wait(1);
      pc.printf("Project HelloWord IKS:  This program runs since %d seconds.\n\r", i++);
      myled = !myled;
  }
}

   Compile > Save As > F: